# Spring Boot: error when activating profile in YAML file

Tags: spring-boot

I can't activate a profile dynamically in a Spring Boot app. I defined profiles in `pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Then I created 2 files in `src/main/resources`:

```
# application.yml

spring:
  application:
    name: myapp-service
  profiles:
    active: @activatedProperties@
server:
  port: 8200
```

Here is `application-dev.yml`:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
redis:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
```

When starting the app from the IDE, it fails to read `active: @activatedProperties@` values rating the error about `@` symbol:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from target/classes/application.yml'
...
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)
 in 'reader', line 5, column 13:
        active: @activatedProperties@
                ^
```

I found some examples of the same use but in `application.properties` file.
Isn'it possible to do the same in a `yml` file ?

I tried to replace it with `$` sign as follows:

```
...
  profiles:
    active: ${activatedProperties}
```

This time it is Spring Boot that raised the error about failing to load `redis.host` value:

```
Factory method 'redisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name must not be null or empty!
```

as if the profile is not recognized.

Here is the configuration file:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class AppConfiguration {
    private String redisHost;
    private int redisPort;
    private String redisPassword;
... //getters and getters come here
```

Here is the Spring Boot application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class LiveDataServiceApplication {

    @Autowired
    private AppConfiguration configuration;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LiveDataServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConfiguration = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(configuration.getRedisHost(), configuration.getRedisPort());
        redisConfiguration.setPassword(configuration.getRedisPassword());
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConfiguration);
    }
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I annotated every attribute in `AppConfiguration` class with `@Value():

```java
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Value("${redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${redis.port}")
    private int redisPort;

    @Value("${redis.password:}")
    private String redisPassword;
...
```

and moved the values to `application.yml`and it worked!
If I keep the vaues in `application-dev.yml` file, it fails to load them.
Why so? It seems like the default profile `dev` is not set.

**UPDATE-2**

Finally, it worked if I use a single YAML file `application.yml` including available environments as follows:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: live-data-service
  profiles:
    active: ${activatedProperties}
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
server:
  port: 8200
redis:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
---
spring:
  profiles: prod
  kafka:
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: prod-kafka.server:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
redis:
  host: prod.server.com
  port: 6379
  password: prod-server-pwd
```

at least locally? I have no idea why id does not when using separate YAML files (`application-dev.yml`, `application-prod.yml`, etc.
Offcial [Spring Boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-configuration-depending-on-the-environment) have no more details about that.

Comment: According to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#maven-profile, you need to enable resource filtering in your pom; did you do this?

Comment: No, you don't need it anymore if you use `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with maven change load.

You have to remove **profiles** part from pom.xml, then load maven changes by clicking on the icon:

[image]

Then again add back the **profiles** part and load maven changes again.

The required profile should start loading again.

**profiles part example:**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>dev</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>dev</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>prod</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is due to no having Spring Boot profile for the required environment.

The profile named 'dev' shown above (included in pom.xml) is a Maven profile, and not a spring profile. Therefore this will not be used for Spring configuration.

**How to solve the problem?**

The problem can be solved by explicitly creating separate Spring profile, and specifying it as a parameter, in these 2 steps:

**Step 1:**   Create separate profile file for each environment (Example: dev / test)

Spring Boot uses a default profile named 'default'.

Values for default profile will be read from
**application.properties** file or **application.yml** file.

Values for a new profile (Example: dev / prod / test) can be specified in separate file named

`application-<profile_name>.[properties / yml]`

- For **dev** profile, the file will be
  ***application-dev.properties*** or ***application-dev.yml***
- For **test** profile, the file will be
  ***application-test.properties*** or ***application-test.yml***

**Step 2:**  Specify the profile name as a run-time parameter to Spring Boot application.

Profile name can be specified using

`-Dspring.profiles.active=profile_name`

or

`--spring.profiles.active=profile_name`

To run the 'dev' profile, the Spring boot app can be started using:

```
$ java -jar spring-boot-demo.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

or

```
$ java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -jar spring-boot-demo.jar
```

**An example to demonstrate the usage of spring boot profiles**

---

1. Define data inside src/main/resources/application-dev.properties (or .yml)

   **File name:** application-dev.properties

   `myData=development-profile`

---

2. Fetch data using `@Value` annotation in Java class

   @Value("${myData}")
   private String myData;

   // ....
   System.out.println("myData = " + myData);
   // ...

---

3. Run the spring boot application using profile as a parameter

   `$ java -jar spring-boot-demo.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev`

   `....`

   `myData = development-profile`

   `...`

**More information:**

https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-profiles-example/

Comment: Thank you for your response. It didn't work for me. I have 2 files now: `application.yml` (containing all the default values) and `application-prod.yml` overriding the default values. I tried 2 different syntaxes for `activatedProperties` in `application.yml`: `active: '@activatedProperties'` and `active: '${activatedProperties}`. The app always started in default mode, even if I start it as you suggested: `java -jar spring-boot-demo.jar --spring.profiles.active=prod`.

Comment: Even if I create a specific `application-dev.yml` file and move dev related values from `application.yml` there, it fails to start because can't read dev related values.

Comment: Hi Belgoros, the profile need not be mentioned in pom.xml file. Creating spring profile file, using the @Value annotation for variable, and specifying the run-time parameter of --spring.profiles.active=dev will be sufficient. The "active: @activatedProperties" statement and pom.xml references can be removed.

Comment: I do set up profiles in `pom.xml` as you could see above.

Comment: Profile in pom.xml file is not required. Profile in pom.xml is only for maven. It will not affect Spring profile. Spring boot profile can be specified and used as follows: (1) Separate application-dev.properties  containing myData: some-data (2) @Value String myData   (3)  java -jar demo.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev

Comment: So, the settings explained [here](http://dolszewski.com/spring/spring-boot-properties-per-maven-profile/) are wrong?

Comment: finally, it worked: (1) removed profiles declared in `pom.xml`. (2) created `application-{env}.yml` files. (3) `mvn clean install`. (4) run `java -jar spring-boot-demo.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev` (or prod). Yay, thanks a lot!